# How to further increase cmdline history size?

Tags: command-history

I have already put the following setting in my `.vimrc` file:

```
set history=1000
```

It's been there for a while, I work in vim on a daily basis, so there have been many commands executed by now. I know from vim help, that duplicates and mapped command-lines are not stored, and it also says:

```
Use the 'history' option to set the number of lines that are remembered
(default: 20).
```

Currently there are around 130 lines in my history (`:his` and <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> vary a little bit, second one has about 90 entries), but in my opinion there should be more. There are some commands missing, like opening certain files or some substitution commands with complex regex. There have not been used for a while, but I have this history size increased long enough.

Is there another limit, which I didn't know about? Or maybe it's not a correct way of increasing cmdline history size?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `:` value in your `'viminfo'` option may limit the number of persisted commands. See [`:help viminfo-:`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#viminfo-%3A):

> ```
> : Maximum number of items in the command-line history to be
>   saved.  When not included, the value of 'history' is used.
> ```

Comment: This might be it. How can I change this setting? `:set viminfo=:1000` will do?

Comment: That would be a non-default value. Check with `:verbose set viminfo?` where this got set, and best change that location. As this option uses a set of values, it's best to use `:set viminfo-=:42 | set viminfo+=:1000` to modify it.

Comment: obviously I have to expand set of values using `+=` instead of just overwriting it. Using verbose I got: `Last set from ~/.vimrc` after some default values. I don't have any setting changing `viminfo` behaviour, so I don't know what to change there. I'll just add this line with `:1000` parameter and accept your answer when I notice increase in history size.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer a bit to show how to do this? Seems like `:set viminfo+=:1000` would do it, but I'm not sure I follow exactly why you subtract 42 from it first.

Comment: @TankorSmash: The 42 isn't subtracted; this intends to remove the `:42` part (42 is just a random number, as the precise number in OP's config isn't known) from the `'viminfo'` option. If you don't have an existing default in there, `set viminfo+=:1000` will indeed be enough.

Comment: Why do you think this is an issue with `viminfo`? @qiubix, did you originally have `:` in your vim info. It seems he has the default values. I also had the default values of `viminfo='100,<50,s10,h`. the `:verbose set viminfo` is not accurate when it's just reporting the default values. I didnt set it anywhere, but it still shows up that I set it in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: .. but I keep losing history. Also if it viminfo has just `:` then the value from history should be used, which in case of OP is `1000`

Comment: I think `:help viminfo-:` is a typo which should be `:help viminfo`.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: No, each viminfo item actually has a separate help anchor.

Answer (score 1):

The `viminfo` value seems to be a comma separated set of values.

In my case I changed:

```
:set viminfo=!,'10000,<50,s10,h
```

to

```
:set viminfo=!,'10000,<50,s10,h,:10000
```

Comment: +=/^= will handle the comma-separated stuff for you

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
if &history < 1000
  set history=1000
endif
```

Source: https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible/commit/f7bdc45c03083d61c3955e54a2ef610b21d2801e

Comment: the poster already had this setting